# Find two disjoint subsets of equal size and product that maximize the size

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $S = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 4096 \}$.
>
> Find two subsets $S_1, S_2 \subseteq S$ that maximize $|S_1|$, where $S_1 \cap S_2 = \varnothing$, $|S_1| = |S_2|$, and $\displaystyle \prod_{m \in S_1} m = \prod_{n \in S_2} n$.

I've tried some small cases, for example, if $T = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 10 \}$, then we can show that $|T_1| \geq 4$ by setting $T_1 = \{1,4,6,10 \}$, $T_2 = \{ 2,3,5,8 \}$. Since $\displaystyle \prod_{n \in T} n = 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7$, it is not possible to assign the element $7$ to one of $T_1$ or $T_2$. So $|T_1| \leq 4$.

To generalize, it seems that we need to count the number of all prime factors whose powers are odd for the upper bound. However, it is not so easy to do this for a large number. Furthermore, it is hard to construct subsets that give a lower bound. I guess maybe there are some ways to find two subsets so that the product of the numbers in each subset is equal. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Update:

Consider $V = \{1,2,\ldots,27\}$, we can construct $V_1, V_2 \subseteq V$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
V_1 &= \{ 1,6,4,15,7,24,9,20,11,26 \}, \\
V_2 &= \{ 3,2,12,5,21,8,18,10,22,13 \}.
\end{align*}
$$

That is, consider all multiples of $2$ and $3$. It can be generalized that for any set $W = \{ 1,2,\ldots,9k \}$, we can construct $W_1,W_2 \subseteq W$ such that $|W_1|=|W_2|= \left\lceil \frac{13k}{4} \right\rceil$ by the above construction.